# Detecting indentations in Python

Tags: python

```
def divide(x, y): 
    try: 
        # Floor Division : Gives only Fractional Part as Answer 
        result = x // y 
        print("Yeah ! Your answer is :", result) 
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print("Sorry ! You are dividing by zero ")

    try: 
        result = x // y 
        print("Yeah ! Your answer is :", result) 
    except: 
        print("An error occurred") 

    try: 
        # Floor Division : Gives only Fractional Part as Answer 
        result = x // y 
        print("Yeah ! Your answer is :", result) 
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print("Sorry ! You are dividing by zero ")
    except NameError: 
        print("Name Error")
    except MemoryError: 
        print("Memory Error")
    except AttributeError: 
        print("Here is some\
            long long error message\
            .....")
```

I have a function that has three `try...except` clauses. My goal is to detect how many separate `try...except` clauses it has (3 in this function) and how many `except` keyword it has in each clause (the first and second one has 1 and the third one has 4).

I tried to import this file by doing

```
with open("test.py", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    ... # getting each line
```

and try to divide the `try...except` clauses by detecting the indentation level.
However, I feel like this is not an exhaustive way of doing it and there might be an easier way.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, but take a look at [the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast). Actually parsing the code and working with it in an in-memory data structure is probably going to be better than guessing from raw text.

Comment: There is no clear way to see if there are useless `try...except` clause. I am trying to detect that.

Comment: How do you define _useless_ `try...except` clause?

Comment: @Sanyash Two types of useless exceptions: 1) has only one except clause and catches a too general exception like Exception and Standard Error, 2) all exception clauses in the statement are empty

Comment: If using an `ast` module is better for this task, any ideas how to detect `try...except` clauses?

Comment: 1) What is _Standard Error_? 2) _empty_ clause means having only `pass` statement like this: `except <something>: pass`?

Comment: @Sanyash 1) Standard error is just an `except` with no error (second `try...except` clause in my question. 2) Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a starting point to use `ast` for your task. With your code example it detects `except` without any exception on line 12 and prints `too broad except, line 12`. Also I tested it with `except Exception:`, the message is the same and with `except ZeroDivisionError: pass`, the message is `useless exception`. You can take it and improve further (work with several functions in module, etc.).

```
import ast

with open('test.py') as f:
    data = f.read()
    module = ast.parse(data)
    function = module.body[0]
    for obj in function.body:
        if isinstance(obj, ast.Try):
            try_block = obj
            for handler in try_block.handlers:
                if handler.type is None:
                    print('too broad except, line {}'.format(handler.lineno))
                    continue
                if handler.type == 'Exception':
                    print('too broad except, line {}'.format(handler.lineno))
                    continue
                if len(handler.body) == 1 and isinstance(handler.body[0], ast.Pass):
                    print('useless except, line {}'.format(handler.lineno))
```

For your goals stated in the question (count `try...except` blocks and count `except` clauses in each block), it is easy, as you can see: `len([obj for obj in function.body if isinstance(obj, ast.Try)])` and `len(try_block.handlers)` will do it.

Comment: This is impressive. Thanks a lot! I have a few questions though. In `function = module.body[0]` and `for obj in function.body:` these two lines, what does `body` indicate? Also, in https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/module-compiler.ast.html it sees like each node types in `ast` have different attributes. Does this affect how a specific keywords in python is detected?

Comment: Can't answer your second question, and for the first I can only show you this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar. `body` can be a list of _something_, where each element of _something_ can be a function, return statement, try statement, etc. or it can be a single expression. For your module you have only one element in `module.body` - it is your function (`FunctionDef` according to the doc) and three `try` (`Try`) statements in function. Also you can inspect `handler.body` and see a list of statements there.